# Using sklearn's cross_val_score with different training and testing datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, testing, scikit-learn, dataset

I have a quick question about the following short snippet of code (my version of sklearn, from which cross_val_score and LinearDiscriminantAnalysis are imported from, is 1.1.1):

```
cv_results = cross_val_score(LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),data,isTarget,cv=kfold,scoring='accuracy')
```

I am trying to train a LinearDiscriminantAnalysis ML algorithm on the 'data' variable and the 'isTarget' variable, which are numpy arrays of the features of the samples in my ML dataset and a list of which samples are targets (1) or non-targets (0), respectfully. kfold is just a method for scoring the algorithm, it isn't important here.

My question is this: I am trying to score this algorithm by training it on 'data' and 'isTarget', but I would like to test it on a different dataset, 'data_val' and 'isTarget_val,' but cross_val_score does not have parameters for training an algoirithm on one dataset and testing it on another. I've been searching for other functions that will do this, and I feel that it is a really simple answer and I just can't find it.

Can someone help me out? Thanks :)

Comment: The reason there's not an easy way to do this is that it's not really the purpose of cross_val_score. The function already automatically creates folds of the data you pass in, trains on one subset and scores against the other subset `cv` times. If you want to make it use the groups or folds you supply, using either the `groups` parameter and a grouping fold iterator like [groupkfold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold), or by creating your own CV splitter that only splits into your train and test splits

Comment: IMO it seems more like you want something like gridsearchCV that implements a `refit` parameter, that can give you a fitted model that you can then score separately against your holdout data set

Comment: Thank you all for the super helpful info! This makes a lot of things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how cross-validation is designed to work. The `cv` argument you are supplying specifies that you want to do K-Fold cross-validation, which means that the entirety of your dataset will be used for both training and testing in K different folds.

You can read up more on cross-validation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a `PredefinedSplit` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit.html)) as the `cv` argument.